# DKIM header tags ordering

Tags: email, dkim

Hi I am new to the mail domain and trying to figure out to parse the digital signature out of the DKIM-Signature header. The "b=" tag gives the value for the digital signature. Is there any ordering in where the "b=" tag should appear (is it always the last tag in the header)?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no ordering in where "b" tag should appear in the DKIM-Signature header. You may very well know that DKIM is self-signatory i.e the signature is computed including the "DKIM signature" header. This has influence on why  "b" tag is added at the end of the signature. It is just done for the sake of convenience of adding the tag's value at the end at once after the computation digital signature of DKIM's signature header.